# How to hide folder path with `Netlify`?

Tags: netlify

I’m hosting a static site with `Netlify`.

My site pages are all in a folder called `pages`.

For example, when I open the `Contact Us` page, it looks like this:

```
mysite.com/pages/contact-us
```

How can I hide the **/pages** path in the url?

`Netlify` uses a `_redirects` file for `redirects/rewrites`.. but I still haven't been able to figure out how.